# How can we identify the special characters that cannot be directly given as GitHub Actions Secrets

Tags: github, github-actions

I was working with GitHub Action pipeline codes and I used Action Secrets for storing secret values. When I added some secrets, I found that it was not working as expected. Later I found out that some special characters cannot be directly given as GitHub Secrets. In my case, it was a '$' symbol and I used escape character '\' to resolve my issue.

How can we find out about the list of special characters that cannot be used directly in GitHub Secrets? As we can't print the secret via pipeline, identifying those by using trial and error is also a tedious task.

Comment: The `$` character as a specific meaning for shell commands, that by be the reason why you need to escape it when used in secrets value. Now, there are many other special characters for shell commands ([here is a reference with bash](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html)) and I agree it could be interesting to know exactly which one can or cannot be used in secrets values without escaping them.